# CSS3 or HTML5 - how do i do a background animation like clouds floating in HTML5 pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just wondering whether there is a way to do a background animations in pure CSS3 based design may be with little bit of a HTML5 or jquery ?

i can see some people do this

http://addtwitter-followers.com/

is there easy way to do this in CSS3 ?

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JzvU5/)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}
#wrap {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url(http://addtwitter-followers.com/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/bck.jpg) top no-repeat #94E3F4;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    animation: animatedBackground 150s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 150s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 150s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 150s linear infinite;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">...</div>
```

---

References

[@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

[animation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

[animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)